# Align text and fa chevron in my header image with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, alignment, responsive

I m new to Bootstrap and  made a  website with online classes! I m now trying to customize for my need. I would like to know how to align my text  and fa-chevron. would like my text on the top of the girl's head and the chevron where i have it now. But the problem is that when i shrink the image to  < 370 the text is masked by my menu and in the landscape mode i loose everything. I tried many combinations!!! Thanks!

my css for that is

```
#home-heading h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: -75px 0 300px 0;
}
```

you can see the site at [enter link description here](http://mgbourgeois.com/bestfreetexteditor/)

Comment: You need to add padding to the content following the fixed navbar, this is mentioned in the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top). Also, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks hungerstar!! tried it looks good on small device now but 1200px and higher not so good. thanks for the info! will read and experiment more. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

try position relative and absolute..

```
#home-content-box-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: relative;
}

#home-heading {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
    animation-delay: .5s;
    position: absolute;
    top: according to ur need 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omi for your help will try later and see what happen! Thanks again! have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try absolute positioning. Add a wrapping div around your content (I'm assuming it's two different elements, but if you show me the markup, you can help me out with that.

```css
#home-heading { height: 500px; width: 100%; background: #000; }
i {color: #fff;}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#home-heading h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

#home-heading i {
    margin-top: 300px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-heading">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <i>Chevron</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Christian for your info will have a look at it today and let you know later.

Answer (score 0):

You should link the text position to the top of page and not use margin to move it. You could make the same with chevorn, adding a class to its div

UPDATE:
Rember to add class chevron to chevron div:
[image]

```
 #home-heading h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

I've apply some change on this also:

```
.chevron{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks vlK !! it works perfectly!! the only thing i m trying to do now is have the title a little more over her head. now the title is too close to her head. tried margin-top:20px;  but nothing happen!

Comment: simply change on #home-heading h3 the value of top from 15% to 13% or 12% or 11% until you have the best position.

Comment: Thanks!!  changed the #home-heading h3 the value of top from 15% to 13% and it worked perfectly. But now my chevron is in the middle of her nose so i tried in .chevron  bottom; 10px; but nothing..is that the way to lower my chevron and if i do it will that affect my title? Thanks

Comment: I've checked your code and you don't add the class chevron to your chevron div, I've update my answer attaching an image of the code you should change. I've change some prop on the .chevron class also.

Comment: Thank you so much VlK! did the change.